# Laravel 5 Update action routes to the show function in controller

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and am creating a basic CRUD application. I am having trouble getting an edit item form to work. I'm sure that the issue is in the form action I am using, but I can't figure it out. I'm using html for the form and not the illuminate Form. The edit action keeps routing to the show function of the controller and not the update function.

routes file

```
Route::resource('vehicles', 'VehiclesController');
```

edit form file

```
<form action="{{ action('VehiclesController@update', $vehicle->id) }}" >

...

{{ method_field('PUT') }} 

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
{{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll recommend you to name that route and than use that name as action for the form:

```
{{ route('example.route', $vehicle->id) }}
```

Here is how to set named routs: [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes)

Comment: Thanks, one line but perfect solution